# Fluid div inside another div

Tags: html, css

I want to get this when resizing the browser window:

[image]

And I have this HTML:

```
<a class="article-link-block" href="#">
<img src="http://c69282.r82.cf3.rackcdn.com/361.jpg">
<div class="article-info">
    Article Info need to be 20% of the height and always at the bottom
</div>
</a>
```

I can get everything but not the 20% of the height for article info.

I can only make it e.g. 50px height and then margin-top: -50px and it is ok, for maximum width. but when I start decreasing the width of the browser it doesn't change the height only the width, which is 100%.

Any advice/techique how can I dynamically resize height and stay at the bottom all the time?

If I use margin-top: -20%; height: 20%; for .article-info

it creates something like that:

[image]
But this is wrong, of course.

Btw. CSS is

```
.article-link-block {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
}

.article-link-block img {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
display: block;
float: left;
}

.article-info {
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    display: block;

        margin-top: -20%;
    height: 20%;

}
```

**EDIT** **EDIT** **EDIT**

```
<body>

    <div id="header">
        <!-- header is 100% width of body width-->
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <!-- container is 100% of body width -->

        <div id="articles"> 

                <!-- articles are 70% of container width-->

                <a class="article-link-block article-1" href="#">
                <img src="http://c69282.r82.cf3.rackcdn.com/361.jpg">
                <div class="article-info">
                    Article Info need to be 20% of the height and always at the bottom
                </div>
                </a>

                <a class="article-link-block article-2" href="#">
                <img src="http://c69282.r82.cf3.rackcdn.com/361.jpg">
                <div class="article-info">
                    Article Info need to be 20% of the height and always at the bottom
                </div>
                </a>

                <a class="article-link-block article-3" href="#">
                <img src="http://c69282.r82.cf3.rackcdn.com/361.jpg">
                <div class="article-info">
                    Article Info need to be 20% of the height and always at the bottom
                </div>
                </a>

                <a class="article-link-block article-4" href="#">
                <img src="http://c69282.r82.cf3.rackcdn.com/361.jpg">
                <div class="article-info">
                    Article Info need to be 20% of the height and always at the bottom
                </div>
                </a>

        </div>

        <div id="sidebar">
                <!-- sidebar is 30% of container width -->
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <!-- footer is 100% of body width -->
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: This may be obvious, but is the image the red area, and `article-info` the grey area?

Comment: can you add some css with that?

Comment: css added. Any advice how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I believe wrapping a block-element in an `<a>` is HTML5 compliant, it's not necessary.

CSS

```
a { position:relative; outline:1px dashed red; display:inline-block; width:100% }

span {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height:20%;
    padding:5px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    width:100%
}

img { width:100% }
```

HTML

```
<p style="background-color:black"><!-- remove inline style in production code -->
    <a href="#" class="article-link-block">
        <img src="http://c69282.r82.cf3.rackcdn.com/361.jpg">
        <span>Article Info need to be 20% of the height and always at the bottom</span>
    </a>
</p>
```

Fiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/9dt7w/

**EDIT** (one picture with multiple articles). Instead of using a `<span>` use a list.

```
<img>
<ul>
  <li>article</li>
  <li>article2</li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle for that one: http://jsfiddle.net/vtZ8g/

**EDIT - Accepted Answer**
http://jsfiddle.net/MXXaS/

Comment: It's not working when you have multiple articles (from a foreach loop). bottom: 0 is creating problems.

Comment: Added a variation to my original answer for this situation.

Comment: Thanks, but the structure is something like this: http://pastebin.com/iHwXbCUp . I have also updated my original post.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. You're structure sucks (not to offend). 1) Either try floating elements or position them. I'd go with position [see answer], as you want them to be 100% width ...`float` is moot in for your design, and may be causing issues, as I don't see you clearing them. 2) `<a><img><div></a>` vs `<p><a><img><ul></a></p>` The latter looks like a paragraph block wrapping an image and list (all linked to something) -- it's a semantic thing -- turn off your CSS and compare both designs.

Comment: Which structure in pastebin? I don't need lists at all after image at all. Img is a background for every article. Btw. everything is fluid. I have only one max-width for a wrapper-all which I didn't put in the structure because it will make things only more complicated. My solution for now is that I am using right now 55px for height a margin-top: -55px and when width of the browser is e.g. 480 I will change it to 40px and if 320 to 30 etc. But I wanted it habe fluid not in steps. Anyway thanks for your time. If nobody else will add an answer I will choose your answer as the best one.

Comment: If you resized your window in the examples I provided, you'd see that they're fluid. I don't blame you for not wanting to put in `steps` as a solution (@media for example). I'll take a look at the pastebin when I get home this evening. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I still like the semantics of my markup better. Please note that my CSS for this requires 0 classes. I'm only using the ids, which you could expand upon for better targeting, if needed (#articles img, #articles span, #articles a, etc.)

Comment: No, your example is not what I was asking for. I need to put that div over that image e.g. like here: http://workshop.rs/projects/jqfancytransitions/ But using percentage and not margin-top: -50px; etc.

Comment: No problem. Take `margin-bottom` off of `img`. That will allow the `span` (or whatever you choose as a container) to overlap the `img`. Thanks for the working example. Last Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MXXaS/

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really have a DIV (a block element) within an 'a' tag. If you change the DIV to be inline I think that may be valid.

In order to get the DIV to be 20% of it's parent you would need to make the 'a' tag a block level element and give it a height too.

Then to align it to the bottom you would need to make the 'a' tag position relative and make the DIV position absolute with a bottom value of '0'.

```
a.article-link-block {
    display:block;
    position:relative
}

.article-info {
    postion:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

}

Comment: the problem is that it do this: http://s9.postimage.org/prz0pdiu7/within.png Btw. position absolute and bottom 0 makes weird stuff. Any advice?

Comment: I have upgraded my css with aditional info

Comment: Take the float left off of the image and the inner DIV.

Comment: Can you provide a wokring examle if possible, because it is not working as you suggest.

Comment: it's not working at all. Try to change your browser size to smaller size.

Comment: I have updated my original post with the structure of my actual website so you have better understanding and uploaded the structure here pastebin.com/iHwXbCUp . Thanks in advance for your help.